# C# Web Application TimeZone Management

Tags: c#, timezone

What is the best approach to manage timezones in a web application? For example A is in the US and he posted something @ 10:00AM then B from other country sees it, when he look at the time it was posted it should be 10:00AM US Time converted into his country's local time. Sorry this is my first time creating an app that will be used internationally so I dont have experience doing something like this.

Comment: Use UTC time always and convert it in client side as local time for viewing/display purposes.

Comment: @JrTabuloc How do I know if my server is saving time in UTC format? Im using MSSQL Server 2008 r2.

Comment: @JrTabuloc also, is it possible to convert the UTC time to the client's local time without getting their timezone upon registration?

Comment: Lots of questions on this already.  Read the best practices docs, the timezone and dst tag wikis, and other questions tagged [tag:timezone].  If you have *specific* questions that haven't been asked before, then please do ask those.  Thanks.